# CUSTOMTKINTER using OpenCV and Mediapipe

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, customtkinter

I am converting my sign language program to an .exe file. It runs smoothly when i run it as a .py.
GUI uses tkinter and i have a start button where after clicing the start button it opens an OpenCv window where mediapipe also runs and detects landmarks. My problem is when i convert it to .exe. It opens the opencv camera but doenst do any detection unlike to the .py format. Any help pleaseeee

I've tried to check the windows console in pyinstaller but still doesnt work. Any workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: please provide a provide a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example